# Separating a function into a different file in C

Tags: c, function

In my code, I have a few void functions that use global variables.

```
int i =0;

void increment()
{
      i++;
}

int main()
{
      increment();
      printf("i = %i\n",i)
}
```

I want to separate the functions into different files, so I move int i; into a header file, and declare the void function there. e.g

```
(in my header file)

int i = 0;
void increment(); 

(in main file)

#include "header.h"

int main()
{
      increment();
      printf("i = %i\n",i);
}
```

When I compile, I get an undefined reference to increment. What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: `gcc -c increment.c`.. `gcc main.c increment.o`

Comment: don't define variables in h files

Answer (score 2):

In your header file, myheader.h,

```
 extern int i;
 extern void increment();
```

In increment.c,

```
 #include "myheader.h"

 void 
 increment()
 {
      i++;
 }
```

In main.c,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "myheader.h"
int i = 0;

int main()
{
     increment();
     printf("i = %i\n",i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Continuing from the comment, you want to avoid the use of *global variables* unless they are absolutely required. You can just as easily separate your function into a separate files and *pass a pointer* to the integer `i` as a parameter to `increment`. It takes little extra effort, and avoids a number of pitfalls, e.g.

**increment.h**

```
void increment (int *i);
```

**increment.c**

```
void increment (int *i)
{
    (*i)++;
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "increment.h"

int main (void) {

    int i = 0, j;

    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {  /* simple loop to call increment 5-times */
        increment (&i);
        printf ("call %d, i : %d\n", j, i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Compile**

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu11 -Ofast increment.c -o bin/main main.c
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/main
call 0, i : 1
call 1, i : 2
call 2, i : 3
call 3, i : 4
call 4, i : 5
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you, I found this to be a very interesting use of dereferencing. Just to make things clear, &i and int *j = i are the same thing right?

Comment: `&i` is the **address of** `i`, `int *j = i;` would be an error: (type mismatch attempting to assign an `int` as an `int *`) `int *j = &i` would be correct. What is happening is the **address of** `i` is passed to `increment`. Why? Because when passing a parameter to a function, the function **receives a copy** of the variable. (updating the value of a copy would not be seen in `main`). To insure the updated value is available in main, you pass the **address of** `i` (insuring that when `i` is updated, the value at the original memory address for `i` is changed, not some copy)

Comment: If it is not clear, the `for` loop and the loop variable `j` have nothing to do with the increment of `i`. The `for` loop is simply used to call the function `increment` 5 times (to show an example of repeated calls incrementing the value of `i`) You could omit the printing of the `j` index completely and it would have no effect on the value of `i`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked with me:

header.h

```
int i = 0;
void increment()
{
    i++;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "header.h"

int main(){

    increment();
    printf("i = %i\n",i);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _I want to separate the functions into different files_

Comment: Why not `void increment(int *i)` and get rid of the *global variable* and instead pass a pointer to a local declared in `main` (cleaner), and you simply need increment `(*i)++;` in `increment`.

Answer (score 0):

Undefined reference error is due to increment is declared in header file but it is not defined in any of your c files
I suggest you code like below:

(in my header file)

```
EXTERN int i;
void increment();
```

(in main file)

```
#define EXTERN
#include "header.h"

int main()
{
      increment();
      printf("i = %i\n",i);
}
```

(in a new c file)

```
#define EXTERN extern
#include "header.h"

void increment()
{
    i++;
}
```